# ng if and property can't be found

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a strange problem which i don't know how to solve. I have a form:

```
<form
      #loginForm
      method="POST"
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      [formGroup]="loginForm"
      (ngSubmit)="onLogin(signinButton)"
    >
```

and inside form i have:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="show; else notShow">
          <button
          #signinButton
          size="50"
          [expanded]="true"
          type="submit">
          </button>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-template #notShow>
          <button
            #signinButton
            priority="1"
            [disabled]="loginFormGroup.controls.login.value.length < 2"
            size="50"
            [expanded]="true"
            type="submit"
          >
           </button>
        </ng-template>
```

My problem is that i get typescript error:
Property 'signinButton' does not exist on type 'LoginFormComponent'.

27           (ngSubmit)="onLogin(signinButton)"

And that happens only when i am using ng container and template. If i use button without ng if and else i to works but i need those conditiions used, i am not sure why i am getting that error and how to solve it.
Anybody have an idea?

Comment: why do you need to put the button referance as a function argument?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I was using it in login to set isDisabled property to true, but now that you mentioned it. I change it not to send it as parameter but to get it from ViewChild. Now the error is gone and i works :)

Comment: Great! Also you can have one additional boolean property(for example `isDisabled`) and do it like this.
`[disabled]="loginFormGroup.controls.login.value.length < 2 || isDisabled"`

Comment: @Ashot Aleqsanyan I will check that too, thx for hint, that hint saved me :)

Comment: Eddy no problem, Glad to help